# Java JComponent - start painting from lower left corner?

Tags: java, graphics, paint, coordinate-systems, jcomponent

I'm overriding the `paintComponent` method for a background in a JComponent and all is going well.

However, I want to start painting from the lower left corner instead of the upper left.

Do I need to transform something, or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use an `AffineTransform` to draw from the lower left corner:

[image: Screenshot]

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    frame.add(new JComponent() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            // save the "old" transform
            AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();

            // update graphics object with the inverted y-transform
            g2d.translate(0, getHeight() - 1);
            g2d.scale(1, -1);

            // draw what you want
            g2d.drawLine(0, 0, 300, 200);

            // restore the old transform
            g2d.setTransform(old);
        }
    });

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks looks like it works, except my image is upside down :/ .  FYI for future users AffineTransform is in `java.awt.geom.AffineTransform`.

Comment: Yes, the transform transforms any call to the graphics object, if you want to draw anything with the "default" transform you need to do it before you have changed it (right after the call to `super.paintComponent(g);`)